# Are there rules that prevent chaos in our world?

Tags: philosophy, science, god

Is it right to say that, if there is no supreme god, there must be a power or set of rules that prevents chaos in our world?

Isn't it natural that if the world is not ruled by god it must be exposed to some set of predetermined rules that prevent total chaos. I mean that the laws of physics are not enough power to keep the world (particularly our earth life) from running into total disorder.
For example according to Aggañña Sutta, the universe shrink and then expand in repeated cycles. I see here one of these predetermined rules - cycles.

Answer (score 4):

My scientific education tells me that:

1. The world is as it is and behaves as it does (and is observed by people).
2. People (scientists) observe that behaviour and then invent rules which describe (or define) the behaviour.

Note that:

- Those rules are not necessarily "pre-determined" (instead they're invented by people to describe the behaviour-of-the-world which they observe)
- The world doesn't obey the rules, instead the rules are chosen to describe the world.

A Buddhist word for those rules is [Dharma or Dhamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma#Buddhism).

The Buddha is praised for his Dhamma, i.e. the Buddha discovered and explained a useful set of "rules" which we use to understand the world.

Comment: So you say that the universe doesn't follow the rules scientists invent. Fine, does leave the possibility for the universe to behave different from the rules? I mean not just the set rules/laws we currently have. And would this mean that we will never have a grand unifying theory that describes anything?

Answer (score 3):

They are called the [Five Niyamas](http://buddhism.about.com/od/basicbuddhistteachings/tp/The-Five-Niyamas.htm). Simply put, they are all processes of causes and effect. If the causes are present, there's an appropriate effect.  If the causes are not present, there's no effect. That's the order of anything in the universe.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into **"Five Niyamas"**.

What are "Five niyamas" - http://www.theravada.dk/?pageid=389

These were introduced by Lord Buddha to explain every event in our reality.

If you can see in many things in nature there is no actual pattern or law it is simply chaos.

**For example**

Imagine the very unusual run that sperm has to take to meet with the female egg.It is complete chaos, but in it only the strongest will win. So what we see is not complete chaos producing more chaos it is simply sanctioned chaos
creating things less chaotic.

for example your brains neurotic activities are complete chaos but that is the thing that creates completely organized thoughts and functions.

In fact the truth is what we see as chaos is only our understanding being incompetent to explain what is happening, Soon as we understand complete chaos turn into very systematic behavior.